# Weblogic 10.3.6: admin console not showing applications

Tags: weblogic

I have the following problem. Admin console of Weblogic 10.3.6:
the *session deployments* is not showing the apps just the libraries.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share with any screen shots or steps you've performed?

Comment: I reviewed the question with one screen shot.

Comment: The Admin Console always work fine, but on last week the more of 60 apps are no longer listed on session deployments anymore. I restarted the admin server, clean cache and tmp and notinhg resolved.

Comment: What happens if you reinstall an app?  Have you looked in config.xml to see if your deployments are listed there?  config.xml will be in the <path_to_domain>/config directory.  You should see an entry for one of the deployments like `<app-deployment>
    <name>APP_NAME</name>
    <target>CLUSTER_OR_INSTANCE</target>
    <module-type>TYPE</module-type>
    <source-path>path/to/source/FILE.TYPE</source-path>
  </app-deployment>`

Answer (score 1):

Click on the link `Customize this table` above `Deployments` title, and the following view will appear :
[image]

click on the check boxes of unwanted nodes(*here node start with `adf..` is the case*)

and then click on the check box of `Exclude libraries when displaying deployments`, and click on the `Apply` button. The nodes starting with `adf` will disappear :

[image]

By clicking on the `reset` button(seen in the first picture), all hidden deployments can be brought back.